# Connectedness of semialgebraic sets via CAD

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I do not know whether there is a standard or some traditional ways to decide whether a semialgebraic set is connected or not.

One way I know is the [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) (CAD) algorithm. I have read some papers on the CAD algorithm, and they mentioned connectedness can be done by using CAD. However, I have not seen any explanation or example.

Can CAD do the connectedness of semialgebraic sets and how? Or any other theoretical way to decide the connectedness of semialgebraic sets?

Comment: Over what field?

Comment: Only real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the CAD algorithm to decompose a semialgebraic set $S$ into a finite set of connected semialgebraic components $S_i$.

We can test whether two such components are adjacent, meaning
$\bar{S_i}\cap\bar{S_j}\cap S\neq\emptyset$, using the standard decision procedure for real-closed fields.

Then we can form a graph $G$ using the components $S_i$ as vertices, with an edge between $S_i$ and $S_j$ iff they are adjacent in the above sense.

Finally we can test whether $G$ is connected, and this will be equivalent to whether $S$ is connected.