# Certificates of connectivity of basic semi-algebraic sets

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, semidefinite-programming, semialgebraic-geometry

Given real polynomials $p_1, \ldots, p_n \in {\mathbb R}[x_1, \ldots, x_d]$, consider the closed basic semi-algebraic set $S \subseteq {\mathbb R}^d$ given by $$S := \{x \in {\mathbb R}^d : p_i(x) \geq 0 \text{ for every $i$}\}$$

I am curious as to whether there any computationally efficient certificates concerning the connectedness of $S$.

Here, I have to be somewhat vague about what it means to be computationally efficient: essentially, I mean a numerical algorithm having polynomial-time complexity which produces either (up to numerical roundoff error):

1. a certificate that $S$ is connected; or
2. a certificate that $S$ has multiple connected components; or
3. an inconclusive answer

with the hope that the third outcome is sufficiently rare, or can be made more and more rare by increasing the degree of the working polynomials, similar to the Lasserre hierarchy in polynomial optimisation.

With this definition of efficiency, an algorithm based on cylindrical algebraic decomposition is not sufficiently fast (though it is deterministic in exact arithmetic).

In the more restrictive case of deciding convexity (rather than connectedness) of basic semi-algebraic sets, there is indeed a fast approach. In 2009, Lasserre developed certificate methods examining the convexity of $S$, see [doi:10.1016/j.aml.2010.04.009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2010.04.009). In essence, his algorithm checks whether the double-variable polynomial $(x,y) \mapsto p_j ( (x+y)/2 )$ is non-negative on $S \times S$ via semidefinite programming (for each $j = 1, \ldots, n$). The approach works in polynomial time and satisfies the above speed requirements.

I like the elegance of this approach to compute certificates of the (non-)convexity of $S$, using the speed of semidefinite programming. I suspect the same cannot be done to derive certificates of connectedness of $S$, though I am not sure. Does anyone here have some thoughts on this? My question is similar to a [previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240266/connectedness-of-semi-algebraic-set-by-c-a-d), but a little more directed in the sense that I am permitting the algorithm to return an answer of "I'm uncertain whether $S$ is connected or not", similar to Lasserre's certificate methods for convexity.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted3.pdf) [PDF]?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In my literature search I did find that reference, however I didn't find the algorithms therein particularly encouraging because of the degree of complexity involved, both in having to implement very intricate algorithms, as well as the computational complexity (which, although singly exponential in the best case, is still far from the speed of semidefinite programming).

Comment: The algorithms in this book are great in that they can provably determine connectivity (with sufficient bit precision), but arguably this is what makes them more computationally expensive than what I'm after. I'm willing to have the possibility of "an inconclusive answer" (as above) for the sake of speed, elegance, and implementation simplicity. This is why I appreciate, e.g., the Lasserre method for examining convexity via semidefinite programming.

Comment: Have you considered all algebraic curves connecting two points?

Comment: In the simplest case of straight paths, this reduces to testing convexity (clearly). In the case of paths $x(t)$ parameterized by higher-degree polynomials, ultimately there would be a need to examine non-negativity of $t \mapsto p_i(x(t))$, which could be much-higher degree polynomial than $p_i$ itself. Is this what you were thinking, or is there some other means of testing "all algebraic curves connecting two points" (for any two points in $S$)?

Comment: Given two points, you can try to decide non-negativity over (algebraic) paths connecting them — say, using SOS decompositions — and then worry about all pairs of points. I have not given this much thought. It may be a stupid proposal.